# Assert arrow function on mocha

Tags: redux, tdd, mocha.js, chai, async.js

I'm trying asserting an action from redux that has an arrow function, and given it creates a new reference, I'm not able to assert it using chai.

Here is the code:

```
export function save(product) {
  return {
    types: ['REQUEST', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED'],
    callAPI: () => fetchSomething()
    payload: {
      product
    }
  };
}

export function saveOrUpdate(product) {
  return product.id ? update(product) : save(product);
}
```

And I tried to do something like this on my test:

```
const action = saveOrUpdate(product);
expect(action).to.be.eql(save(product));
```

This haven't worked because of the callAPI property, so I've tried this approach using chai-subset, ignoring the property callAPI, but it feels like hack:

```
const action = saveOrUpdate(product);
const {types, payload} = save(product);
expect(action).to.containSubset({
   types,
   payload
});
```

Is there anyway to assert using the first approach?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think the problem is that you're calling `save` as a parameter to `eql` function. Maybe we need to find another way to check that `save` was called instead of `update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out, the way you have your code each time the `save` function is called, the JavaScript virtual machine has to create a new `Function` instance. You could just replace that with a reference to a single function that is created once and for all and is reused. **This would make testing for equality trivial.**

If you are concerned about `callAPI` being called with bad arguments, you can wrap `fetchSomething` like I'm doing here;

```
function callFetchSomething() {
    fetchSomething();
}

export function save(product) {
  return {
    types: ['REQUEST', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED'],
    callAPI: callFetchSomething,
    payload: {
      product
    }
  };
}
```

If you do not need protection from incorrect calls, then you could just have `callAPI: fetchSomething`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Chai Spies](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-spies/) to check that `save` method was called.

```
var spy = chai.spy(save);
const action = saveOrUpdate(product);
expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
```